# Which is faster: Searching by string in 1d vector or searching by vector in 2d vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am wondering which data storage method is faster in terms of searching. Keep in mind these structures are unsorted. For example, I store my data like this:

```
vector<vector<int >> vals;
vals.push_back({1,2,3});
```

and I want to search if

```
{1,2,3}
```

is in my vector.

I can also store my data like this:

```
vector<string> vals;
vals.push_back("1 2 3");
```

and search if

```
"1 2 3"
```

is in my vector.

Which of these methods, in terms of both time and space, is more efficient?

Comment: Try both, measure, then proceed.  That is the standard workflow when wondering if X is better than Y.

Comment: Would depend on the implementation of the equality operators for those types.

Comment: or better yet, just worry about getting it right first, then if it's not fast enough, measure and optimize then.   You'll probably be surprised where your bottleneck actually is.

Comment: Since you are storing the values as string in the second case, there will definitively be dependence on the actual values.

Comment: Depending on what you're using them for, you may not have a choice anyway.

Comment: Is there an upper limit on the size of the inner vector? I mean, is it always three elements? How about an upper limit on the numbers themselves? Are they always a single digit? The most efficient storage method if you need to store three tiny numbers would be `std::array<int8_t, 3>` which is just 3 bytes. Of course, I've made a lot of assumptions in reaching that conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to space optimization as it stands here, the string implementation might actually be more efficient as `"1 2 3"` takes up 6 bytes. However if any of the numbers rise to more than 1 decimal, the storage increases.

The vector of ints on the other hand take up a known 3*4 = 12 bytes.

Saving numbers as a string though is not the best idea. If you need to treat them as numbers you would need to convert back and forth. Additionally it's very confusing having a vector of strings and treating them as numbers - remember that the type of an object tells you something about what the object is and does.

Instead - depending on what size of numbers you're expecting - you could use a `char` / `uint8_t` to store your numbers. Then you're down to 3 bytes pr entry.

Specifically, you could probably write it something like this:

```
struct nums{
  uint8_t x;
  uint8_t y;
  uint8_t z;
}

auto vals = std::vector<nums>();
vals.push_back({0,2,3});
```

However it might be nice to use some of the newer c++ features:

```
auto vals = std::vector<std::tuple<uint8_t,uint8_t,uint8_t>>();
vals.push_back(std::make_tuple(0,2,255));
auto result = std::find(vals.begin(),vals.end(),std::make_tuple(0,2,255));
```

Comment: It would probably make more sense to use `std::array` rather than `std::tuple`. I find tuples to be unpleasant to use and only really useful for metaprogramming.

Comment: Also, you should avoid using `char` to store numbers because its signedness is implementation defined. I think you meant to say `int8_t` / `uint8_t`